# Asp.net validators are no longer firing on client side

Tags: asp.net, validation

Early in my project they were working fine. Now the client side validation isn't working, it wants to post back before telling me that a required field is required.

It's not working on my local environment nor on the server. Is there possibly some scripts that aren't getting copied? Did I delete a required reference? I'm using a project type, not web site type with .Net 4.

I tried starting a new project and copying over my form, and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a problem with routing.

Viewed the source of the page, clicked on the validation script, and it wasn't going to the right place :/

```
routes.Add(new Route(
            "{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}", new StopRoutingHandler())
            );
```